# TIMESTAMPADD() is giving me an operand error inside the where clause and I cant figure out why

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server, sql-date-functions

I am using a version of SQL for Advantage Databases.

In the below code, I am attempting to retrieve the total amount from the past year for each customer. However, the TIMESTAMPADD() WHERE function will not work in its current form and gives me an error  **"[iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]Invalid operand for operator: >"**

```
SELECT 
    Maccount.SortName AS Customer,
    SUM(Journal.GLAmount) AS Billings
FROM Journal
    INNER JOIN MAccount
        ON Journal.MAccountPkey=MAccount.MAccountPkey
WHERE Journal.Type=150
AND   Journal.Date > TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_YEAR,-1,CURDATE())
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

I have tried moving the timestampadd() to a HAVING clause, where it is giving me the same error. The function works fine by itself, so I know it isn't a syntax error within the function itself.

Journal.Date < CURDATE(), for example, works fine in the where clause, so I'm not exactly sure why it will not accept a ">" with this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not super-familiar with Advantage, but do you think it's likely an issue related to data-type mismatching?  Maybe try using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() within the TIMESTAMPADD() function, rather than CURDATE()?  Otherwise, it's a mismatch between the data-type of your Journal.Date column, and that actual data-type that is being returned by the TIMESTAMPADD() function

Comment: What type is `Journal.Date` ?

Comment: @Craig, Journal.Date is a datetime-type (mm-dd-yyy-hh-mm-ss). Although, in past reports, there has been no issues comparing Journal.Date with either datetime or date. As mentioned in the post, Journal.Date workes fine with CURDATE() alone. I have tried both CURDATE() and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() within the function.

Comment: Check the documentation: The TIMESTAMPDIFF function returns a TIMESTAMP, whereas the CURDATE() function returns a DATE. I think the solution is to use the following: Cast(Journal.Date AS SQL_TIMESTAMP) > TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_YEAR,-1,CURDATE())

Comment: ... or:
Journal.Date < Cast( TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_YEAR,-1,CURDATE()) AS SQL_DATE)